# React Invalid left-hand side in assignment when checking data values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to render a div based on a value from the state which gets set using `useEffect`, but I keep coming up with errors.

The first error I am seeing is `Syntax error: Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression` with the following code;

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { authenticationService } from "services/auth.service";

const Dashboard = () => {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        authenticationService.currentUser.subscribe(x => setCurrentUser(x));
    });
    
    return (
        <>
            {currentUser && currentUser.login_count = 1 ? <div>First login</div> : <div>Not first login</div>}
        </>
    )
}

export default Dashboard;
```

If I just use the following;

```
{currentUser.login_count = 1 ? <div>True</div> : <div>False</div>}
```

I get `TypeError: Cannot set property 'login_count' of null`

All I want to do is display a div if it is the first time a user logs in based off the `login_count`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: {currentUser.login_count = 1 ? <div>True</div> : <div>False</div>} you are trying to assign value 1 it should be ===.

Comment: @Srivastava That may lead to type coercion. It is recommended to use `===`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` is used to assign values. To compare, you have to use `===`.

So your code will be

```js
{currentUser.login_count === 1 ? <div>True</div> : <div>False</div>}
```

Comment: I am still getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'login_count' of null with this

Comment: @CodeSauce Just use an optional chaining operator to avoid the TypeError. 

> {currentUser?.login_count === 1 ? <div>True</div> : <div>False</div>}

Comment: @DarshShah Is that the same as doing {currentUser && currentUser.login_count === 1 .... ?

Comment: @CodeSauce Yes. I've written a blog on Optional Chaining operator. Refer to this blog: https://iamdarshshah.hashnode.dev/optional-chaining-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign value 1, instead of checking for the condition. Give `===`

```
{currentUser.login_count === 1 ? <div>True</div> : <div>False</div>}
```

Comment: I am still get TypeError: Cannot read property 'login_count' of null with this

Comment: The state currentUser might not have login_count property or do a null check